# WebApplicationInitializer not working after upgrading spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My code used to works well before I upgraded spring-boot-starter-parent from *1.0.2.RELEASE* to *2.1.0.RELEASE*.

When the version of spring-boot-starter-parent is *1.0.2.RELEASE*, I could deploy this project to tomcat, run tomcat, and when I type localhost:8080/greeting.html on my browser I could see 'Hello World".

But after I upgrade the version to *2.1.0.RELEASE* and do the same thing, I just got a *404 not found* error.

**QUESTION**: How can I fix this problem with version *2.1.0.RELEASE* of spring-boot-starter-parent?

Here is my code snippet and the pom file:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.pluralsight</groupId>
    <artifactId>event-tracker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>event-tracker</name>
    <description>An app to track our Events</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <!--<version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>-->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

WebConfig:

```
package com.pluralsight;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pluralsight")
public class WebConfig {
}
```

WebAppInitializer:

```
package com.pluralsight;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.pluralsight.WebConfig");
        return context;
    }
}
```

HelloController:

```
package com.pluralsight.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
    public String sayHello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World");

        return "hello.jsp";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even have a  `WebAppInitializer` you are basically bypassing Spring Boot with that. Instead you should have a class extending `SpringBootServletInitializer` .

Comment: @M.Deinum I followed a tutorial about Spring MVC 4(https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/spring-mvc4-introduction/table-of-contents) of which the demo uses `WebAppInitializer`.

Comment: Then either use a different tutorial as this has nothing to do with Spring Boot or you aren’t following the tutorial. If you aren’t using SPring Boot then remove the starters and/or build a regular jar or create an `@SpringBootApplication` annotation class which also extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` as explained d in the spring boot references guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this [link](https://www.programmergate.com/deploy-spring-boot-application-external-tomcat/)

Instead of **WebAppInitializer** class write Application class as in above link and declare **start-class** tag in properties.

It should work.

Comment: I followed the tutorial in link, except that I keep my *onStartup* method for customizing dispatcher. Still return 404 error.